# Date arithmetic in Erlang

Tags: datetime, date, erlang, date-arithmetic

I have a date in this format `{Y,M,D}`. Is there any good supporting libraries or, tricks I can use to simply, say subtract three months from this date without running into problem with invalid dates, leap years, etc.

My latest similar use is in MySql where you can type:

```
Select '2011-05-31' - Interval 3 Month;
```

which yields `'2011-02-28'`. I am not interested in how to write this library myself, that is what I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [edate](https://github.com/dweldon/edate) - specifically the shift function.

```
> edate:shift({2011,5,31}, -3, months).
{2011,2,28}
```

Under the hood it uses the calendar module, so it correctly deals with all of the corner cases.

Answer (score 22):

```
1> calendar:gregorian_days_to_date(calendar:date_to_gregorian_days({2011, 7, 14}) - 90).     
{2011,4,15}
```

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html

Comment: This works well without downloading a third party module, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I created a GitHub gist with some useful utilities for this sort of thing. Feel free to steal from it if you want.

https://gist.github.com/104903